# How to use extend in usecase when different users are making accounts of different types?

Tags: design-patterns, web, uml, use-case

Following is the usecase created by me for a web-based application. My question is, am i using the right method of extending the use case and if i should draw system boundary too, if so then please tell me the way in which i can draw the boundary as well as use extend?

[image: Use CASE Diagraam]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While these kinds of diagrams tend to have all kinds of notations as I see I will not be saying this one is wrong or right. I do however think there are some points that could be changed:

---

The small people you draw in a use case diagram are actors, which means that any user defined for the system will be included in this use case diagram (should they have a use case). In this particular system it would seem like you have called one of the actors: "Actor" which seems slightly off. Ask yourself, who is "Actor"? Is it a random person? A customer? Perhaps it should have that name?

As for the extend part: extend refers to a use case extending another use case. In this diagram it would seem like one of the actors is actually a use case?

Another note is the database package which you include in the use case diagram. This is something that defines the implementation and has no place in this diagram.

---

A possible but very incomplete (leaving you some work) use case diagram could look like:

[image]

Comment: if i delete the database, state "USER" instead of ACTOR, then how can i use extend?

Comment: The keyword Extend isn't really needed in this design as far as I can see. Also I just noticed that your teacher actor has 2 times the same use case "Comments on Project"

Comment: Thankyou so much.
can u please suggest me, if i should make sub usecases of Teacher, Student, User or i should make sub usecases of the things like, "LOGIN [open login page, enter password, enter username ]", "PROFILE"[edit profile, change name etc] ?

Comment: You shouldn't neccesarily have sub use cases. If you were to choose from the two options you gave I would go for the second one though.